# OpenCV Mahalanobis function to calculate distance between two images

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm using OpenCV to test the similarity between two images taken from the same environment.

I have a series of photos of the same moving environment. So being A and B two binary images of the edges of two sequential images of this environment, I do the following:

```
Mat mean;
mean.create(a.rows, a.cols, a.type());

mean += a;
mean += b;
mean/=2;

Mat covar, mean;

calcCovarMatrix(mean, covar, mean, COVAR_NORMAL | COVAR_ROWS, CV_8UC1);

Mat icovar = covar.inv();

std::cout<<"type a:"<<a.type()<<"\n";
std::cout<<"type b:"<<b.type()<<"\n";
std::cout<<"icovar type:"<<icovar.type()<<"\n";
std::cout<<"a cols:"<<a.cols<<"\n";
std::cout<<"a rows:"<<a.rows<<"\n";
std::cout<<"b cols:"<<b.cols<<"\n";
std::cout<<"b rows:"<<b.rows<<"\n";
std::cout<<"icovar cols:"<<icovar.cols<<"\n";
std::cout<<"icovar rows:"<<icovar.rows<<"\n";

double mahalDistance = Mahalanobis(a, b, icovar);
```

The matrixes are all the same type and have the following values:

```
type a:5
type b:5
icovar type:5
a cols:1280
a rows:400
b cols:1280
b rows:400
icovar cols:1280
icovar rows:1280
```

The mahalanobis distance function throws an error as following:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == v2.type() && type == icovar.type() && sz == v2.size() && len == icovar.rows && len == icovar.cols) in Mahalanobis, file /Users/felipefujioka/Documents/Developer/tg/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 2486
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/felipefujioka/Documents/Developer/tg/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:2486: error: (-215) type == v2.type() && type == icovar.type() && sz == v2.size() && len == icovar.rows && len == icovar.cols in function Mahalanobis

I'd apreciate to know where I'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You mix `a` with `ma` and `b` with `mb` in your code. Have you tried with `Mahalanobis(ma, mb, icovar)`?

Comment: Sorry, there are just A and B, just a typo, the sizes and the mahalanobis are calculated with the same matrices

Answer (score 0):

According  with docs:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#double%20Mahalanobis%28InputArray%20v1,%20InputArray%20v2,%20InputArray%20icovar%29

A and B must be 1D array not matrices